# spotify ivalid redirectURI

Tags: javascript, api, authentication, spotify, spotify-app

I am trying to have a user be authenticated by spotify, in order to pull their data into my web app.

```
export const loginUrl = `${authEndpoint}? client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scopes.join("%20")}&response_type=token&show_dialog=true`;
```

when I was building my project in my local host,  my redriectURI was localhost:3000. Now I switched it to the url to where its being hosted (https://spotify-d5030.web.app try it yourself), both in my code, and on the spotify developer console online. Not sure what to do or how to fix the problem

Comment: You need to change the ```redirectUri``` both in your code and in Spotify Dashboard. The problems occurs because they're not match.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to register each redirect URI to Spotify's developer dashboard:

https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/